# can't user variable outside function

Tags: php, scope

I am trying to make my submit button a diffrent color and disable it in some of my if statements but for some reason if I echo `$submitButtonColor & submitButtonDisabled` outside of my function it does not get the new color. If I echo them inside my function voucher then it works just fine.
I have to use them outside the fuction because I have to use them later in the HTML.

So my problem is that I cant use my variable outside the function even though I am using $GLOBALS

*index.php*

```
<?php
    $date = "";
    $begin = "";
    $tijdsduur = "";
    $aantal = "";
    $color = "#29abe2";
    $discountAmount = "";
    $voucherexpired = "none";
    $voucherexists = "none";
    $getVoucherList = "https://www.planyo.com/rest/?method=list_vouchers&api_key=YOURKEY&resource_id=110556";
    $cleanVoucherList = preg_replace("/ /", "%20", $getVoucherList);
    $voucherlist = file_get_contents("$cleanVoucherList");
    $voucherList = json_decode($voucherlist, true);
    $submitButtonColor = "#29abe2";
    $submitButtonDisabled = "";

    function voucher()
    {
        $testsubject = $_POST['voucher'];
        $doesvoucherexists = false;
        foreach($GLOBALS['voucherList']['data']['results'] as $testVoucher => $testVoucherArr) {
            if ($testsubject == $testVoucherArr['code']) {
                $doesvoucherexists = true;
                if (date("Y-m-d") <= $testVoucherArr['rental_end_date']) {
                    $GLOBALS['discountAmount'] = $testVoucherArr['discount_value'];
                    $GLOBALS['submitButtonColor'] = "#29abe2";
                    $GLOBALS['submitButtonDisabled'] = "";
                    echo "<span style='color: #cc00cc'>De voucher " . $testsubject . " is gebruikt voor een korting van €" . $GLOBALS['discountAmount'] . "</span>";
                }
                else {
                    $GLOBALS['voucherexpired'] = "inline";
                    $GLOBALS['submitButtonColor'] = "#cc00cc";
                    $GLOBALS['submitButtonDisabled'] = "disabled";
                    echo "<span style='color: #cc00cc'>Deze voucher is verlopen</span>";
                }
                break;  
            }
        }
        if ($doesvoucherexists === false && $testsubject == ""){
                $GLOBALS['submitButtonColor'] = "#29abe2";
                $GLOBALS['submitButtonDisabled'] = "";
        }elseif ($doesvoucherexists === false){
            $GLOBALS['voucherexists'] = "inline";
            $GLOBALS['submitButtonColor'] = "#cc00cc";
            $GLOBALS['submitButtonDisabled'] = "disabled";
            echo "<span style='color: #cc00cc'>Deze voucher is niet geldig</span>";
        }
    }
    echo $GLOBALS['submitButtonColor'] . $GLOBALS['submitButtonDisabled']; 

    if (isset($_POST['date']) && isset($_POST['quantity'])) {
      if (isset($_POST['date'])) {
        voucher();
        $date = $_POST['date'];
        $begin = $_POST['begin'];
        $tijdsduur = $_POST['eind'];
        $aantal = $_POST['quantity'];
        $eind = $begin + $tijdsduur;
        $startTijd = "$date " . $begin;
        $eindTijd = "$date " . $eind . ":00";
        $canmakereservation = "https://www.planyo.com/rest/?method=can_make_reservation&api_key=YOURKEY&resource_id=110556&start_time=$startTijd&end_time=$eindTijd&quantity=$aantal";
        $cleancanmakereservation = preg_replace("/ /", "%20", $canmakereservation);
        $reservationavailable = file_get_contents("$cleancanmakereservation");
        $reservationAvailable = json_decode($reservationavailable, true);
        $getrentalprice = "https://www.planyo.com/rest/?method=get_rental_price&api_key=YOURKEY&resource_id=110556&quantity=1&start_time=$startTijd&end_time=$eindTijd&quantity=$aantal";
        $cleanRentalPrice = preg_replace("/ /", "%20", $getrentalprice);
        $rentalprice = file_get_contents("$cleanRentalPrice");
        $rentalPrice = json_decode($rentalprice, true);
        $price = $rentalPrice['data']['total'] - $GLOBALS['discountAmount'];

        if ($reservationAvailable['data']['is_reservation_possible'] == true){
          $color = "#29abe2";
          echo "Uw huurprijs exclusief borg: €" . $price;
        }else{
          $color = "#cc00cc";
          echo $reservationAvailable['data']['reason'];
            $GLOBALS['submitButtonColor'] = "#cc00cc";
            $GLOBALS['submitButtonDisabled'] = "disabled";

        }
        echo "$color";
      }
      exit;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: You should pass submitButtonColor and submitButtonDisabled as parameters of your function voucher() to have acces to them inside your function, and then return their values to have it outside your function

Comment: I don't have to use `$GLOBALS` then right ?

Comment: Yes, the logic is the same than the following answer

Comment: I have added them as parameters and returned them but it does not solve the problem

Comment: I want to give you a link to help but it is not really supposed to be on the internet yet @Med

Answer (score 0):

If I understand enough what you want to achieve.
Basically, you want to change variable value inside the function and access the result outside the function. to do that, you can do :

Make a Function :

```
function voucher($btnDisabled){
 if(someConditions == true){
   $btnDisabled = "disabled";
 }else{
   $btnDisabled = "enabled";
 }
 return $btnDisabled;
}
```

call your function and pass the `$submitButtonDisabled` as parameter :

```
$submitButtonDisabled  = '';

 voucher($submitButtonDisabled);

//in here, $submitButtonDisabled become 'disabled' or 'enabled' based on the conditions;
$submitButtonDisabled;
```

Hope you understand ~

Comment: Your answer misses the return of the values, as the OP wants to use the modified values outside the function

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
    $date = "";
    $begin = "";
    $tijdsduur = "";
    $aantal = "";
    $color = "#29abe2";
    $discountAmount = "";
    $voucherexpired = "none";
    $voucherexists = "none";
    $getVoucherList = "https://www.planyo.com/rest/?method=list_vouchers&api_key=YOURKEY&resource_id=110556";
    $cleanVoucherList = preg_replace("/ /", "%20", $getVoucherList);
    $voucherlist = file_get_contents("$cleanVoucherList");
    $voucherList = json_decode($voucherlist, true);
    $submitButtonColor = "#29abe2";
    $submitButtonDisabled = "";

    function voucher($submitButtonColor = "#29abe2", $submitButtonDisabled  = "" )
    {
        $testsubject = $_POST['voucher'];
        $doesvoucherexists = false;
        foreach($GLOBALS['voucherList']['data']['results'] as $testVoucher => $testVoucherArr) {
            if ($testsubject == $testVoucherArr['code']) {
                $doesvoucherexists = true;
                if (date("Y-m-d") De voucher " . $testsubject . " is gebruikt voor een korting van €" . $GLOBALS['discountAmount'] . "";
                }
                else {
                    $GLOBALS['voucherexpired'] = "inline";
                    submitButtonColor = "#cc00cc";
                    $submitButtonDisabled = "disabled";
                    echo "Deze voucher is verlopen";
                }
                break;  
            }
        }
        if ($doesvoucherexists === false && $testsubject == ""){
                $submitButtonColor = "#29abe2";
                $submitButtonDisabled = "";
        }elseif ($doesvoucherexists === false){
            $GLOBALS['voucherexists'] = "inline";
            $submitButtonColor = "#cc00cc";
            $submitButtonDisabled = "disabled";
            echo "Deze voucher is niet geldig";
        }

        return array('submitButtonDisabled' => $submitButtonDisabled, 'submitButtonColor' => $submitButtonColor);
    }
    //echo $GLOBALS['submitButtonColor'] . $GLOBALS['submitButtonDisabled']; 

    if (isset($_POST['date']) && isset($_POST['quantity'])) {
      if (isset($_POST['date'])) {
        $tmp = voucher($submitButtonColor, $submitButtonDisabled);
        $submitButtonDisabled = $tmp['submitButtonDisabled']
        $submitButtonColor = $tmp['submitButtonColor']
        echo $submitButtonColor . $submitButtonDisabled; 
        $date = $_POST['date'];
        $begin = $_POST['begin'];
        $tijdsduur = $_POST['eind'];
        $aantal = $_POST['quantity'];
        $eind = $begin + $tijdsduur;
        $startTijd = "$date " . $begin;
        $eindTijd = "$date " . $eind . ":00";
        $canmakereservation = "https://www.planyo.com/rest/?method=can_make_reservation&api_key=YOURKEY&resource_id=110556&start_time=$startTijd&end_time=$eindTijd&quantity=$aantal";
        $cleancanmakereservation = preg_replace("/ /", "%20", $canmakereservation);
        $reservationavailable = file_get_contents("$cleancanmakereservation");
        $reservationAvailable = json_decode($reservationavailable, true);
        $getrentalprice = "https://www.planyo.com/rest/?method=get_rental_price&api_key=YOURKEY&resource_id=110556&quantity=1&start_time=$startTijd&end_time=$eindTijd&quantity=$aantal";
        $cleanRentalPrice = preg_replace("/ /", "%20", $getrentalprice);
        $rentalprice = file_get_contents("$cleanRentalPrice");
        $rentalPrice = json_decode($rentalprice, true);
        $price = $rentalPrice['data']['total'] - $GLOBALS['discountAmount'];

        if ($reservationAvailable['data']['is_reservation_possible'] == true){
          $color = "#29abe2";
          echo "Uw huurprijs exclusief borg: €" . $price;
        }else{
          $color = "#cc00cc";
          echo $reservationAvailable['data']['reason'];
            $submitButtonColor = "#cc00cc";
            $submitButtonDisabled = "disabled";
        }
        echo "$color";
      }
      exit;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: I think there is something wrong with closing thing because my html after the php does not work anymore.